# i'd like to use a barchart to visualize sound in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, bar-chart

obviously i'd like the bars to move when the sound plays. I play a small audio file in a fixed pattern, but i can't find how to do this online. either it seems that i'm missing a file that i'd have to download to analyze it or there is a value i need to fill in that they didn't explain. can somebody show me a simple way of doing this?
thanks in advance
code i use:

```
var noise, env;
var seq = "o x o x o x o x o x o x o x x x";
var steps = seq.split(" ");
env = new p5.Env(0.01, 1, 0.2, 0.1);  
function hitMeSteve(when, env, loc) {
  if (when == 'x' && frameCount % speed == 0) {
    env.play();
  }
}
var now = steps[count % steps.length];
  hitMeSteve(now, sf, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a Javascript API that does this. They have an example and it looks fairly simple. 
You can check it out [HERE](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Analyser-Bars-Animation-HTML-Audio-API-Tutorial/).
Hope that helps

Comment: well, i'm working in P5. does it work like that? because i see it's talking about html, but i don't use that there

Comment: @RamsesBeauBams First of all, you never mentioned that you were using p5.js library. Second, how is it that you are not using html? p5.js is a library for webpages.. What are you using then?? Third, Please provide some code if you want help.

Comment: i'm sorry for not mentioning that. maybe it uses html, but i don't use those <html> and <head> thing. i'm just using sketch.js. teacher didn't really explain what that is. 
var noise, env;
var seq = "o x o x o x o x o x o x o x x x";
var steps = seq.split(" ");
env = new p5.Env(0.01, 1, 0.2, 0.1);  
function hitMeSteve(when, env, loc) {
  if (when == 'x' && frameCount % speed == 0) {
    env.play();
  }
}
var now = steps[count % steps.length];
  hitMeSteve(now, sf, 10);
I think that's everything related to the sound

Comment: It hurt my eyes to look at what you wrote @RamsesBeauBams.. Sorry